# ¿Cómo comparar si dos objetos dentro de un array tienen una propiedad con igual valor en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Tengo problemas para resolver lo siguiente:
Tengo un array de objetos (productos de un carrito), y estos objetos tienen el mismo tipo de propiedades(nombre, id, precio, cantidad, etc.)
Lo que necesito hacer, es que en caso de que haya objetos repetidos (con mismo id), se elimine el repetido y se aumente el contador en el objeto que permanezca.

Lo que he hecho es una función que primero ordena los productos, y después evalúa si el objeto coincide con el anterior, y en caso de ser verdad, se aumenta el contador en uno de ellos, borrando el anterior. El problema viene cuando hay mas de dos objetos repetidos, ya que el contador del anterior ahora sería 2, por lo que el objeto no sería igual a pesar de tener igual id.

Mi pregunta entonces sería, ¿podría evaluar si los id de los objetos coinciden? Y de ser asi, ¿de que forma podría?. Les agradezco desde ya por su respuesta.

```
function sortAndfilterItems(item){
  item.sort((a,b)=>{
      if (a.id<b.id){
          return -1;
      }
      if (a.id>b.id){
          return 1;
      }
      return 0;
  })
  let objFiltrados = []

  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    if( JSON.stringify(item[i]) == JSON.stringify(item[i-1])){
        objFiltrados.pop()
        let data = {
            ...item[i],
            count : item[i].count += 1
        }
        objFiltrados.push(data);
    } else {
        objFiltrados.push(item[i])
    }
  }
  return objFiltrados;
```